# Android - Activity doesn't reach onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android application that simply saves data and displays them in a list view, very similar to the Notepad tutorial. Unfortunately my Add activity seems to have stopped working somewhere along the line. When I attempt to add data and press Confirm, it reloads the Activity (the screen flickers slightly) and any data I have entered into the fields is cleared . I have confirmed that it is not reaching onSaveInstanceState(). I was under the impression that this method was called automatically upon finish(), and like I mentioned it was working at one time. Maybe someone can spot where I have introduced an error into my code? I'll paste what I believe are the relevant parts:

```
 confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Verify that fields are filled out
            String description = mDescriptionText.getText().toString();
            String amount = mAmountText.getText().toString();
            if(description.length() == 0 || amount.length() == 0) {
                if(description.length() == 0) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "A description is required";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "An amount is required";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }
            else {
                /* Call this to set the result that your activity will return to its caller */
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                /* Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to 
                whoever launched you via onActivityResult() */ 


                finish();
            }
        }


    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("expEdit","onSaveInstance State Reached");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(EZBudgetDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}


 private void saveState() {
    Log.i("expEdit","saveState Reached");
    String description = mDescriptionText.getText().toString();
    String amount = mAmountText.getText().toString();
    Double dAmount = 0.0;
    if(amount != "") {
        dAmount = Double.valueOf(amount).doubleValue();
    }

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mExpDbHelper.createExpenditure(description, dAmount);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }

        if (mSaveDesc.isChecked()) {
            // Save the description to the CommonDesc table
            mCommDbHelper = new CommonDescDbAdapter(this);
            mCommDbHelper.open();
            mCommDbHelper.createCommonDesc(description);

        }

    } else {

        mExpDbHelper.updateExpenditure(mRowId, description, dAmount);

        if (mSaveDesc.isChecked()) {
            // Save the description to the CommonDesc table
            mCommDbHelper = new CommonDescDbAdapter(this);
            mCommDbHelper.open();
            mCommDbHelper.createCommonDesc(description);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: *I was under the impression that this method was called automatically upon finish()* If you call `finish` you tell Android that you don't need the activity so there is no point on calling `onSaveInstanceState`, especially as you opened that activity as a sub-activity(?).

Comment: Ok it sounds like I am having issues about where my update function should reside then. I have seen instances of passing the update parameters in a bundle to the main activity for processing, would that be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onSaveInstanceState() is not called after finish(). See following [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

and your code is not clean. Never duplicate code for nothing. You should use

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    if(description.length() == 0) {                    
        text = "A description is required";                 
    } else {                    
        text = "An amount is required";                    
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
```

Comment: What does "kill" mean? when you kill something, you are shutting down that something without the something wanting it. Android kills the app when it needs ressources. When you finish your Activity you are not killing your activity, you are closing it, you decided to close it.